# Double quotes appearing when single quotes were used

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bundling-and-minification

I have the following line of Javascript code:

```
shell.flash.success('Some string');
```

However in Chrome Developer Tools this is appearing as:

```
o.flash.success("Some string")
```

(nb. `o` instead of `shell` because it's minified)

I noticed the same thing in IE.

Why does it display the string with double quotes when single quotes were used?

Comment: Maybe your minifying engine is doing that?

Comment: Why does that matter anyway?

Comment: @AkashTomar it matters because of the concept of "leaky abstractions". Basically it's good to know what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: A minifier will produce *equivalent but not identical* code. Why exactly it would choose one quoting style over the other depends on the specifics of the minifier. It doesn't have much to do with leaky abstractions, since there's nothing leaky here; the two quoting styles are interchangeable without affecting behaviour.